# How to disable ASUS driver automatic installation on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, security, mouse

My Windows 10 Pro machine is used for handling sensitive data, so I do not install anything but an endpoint protection software, and everything is installed in Hyper-V containers.

I accidentally connected an ASUS mouse. Very soon I started receiving a nagging popup that I should install the Armoury Crate app (whatever that is), and I was very annoyed by this.

I did some investigation and it turned out that, without my consent, this freakin' mouse + Windows Update silently

- created two devices (TUF Gaming M5 mouse and TUF Gaming M5 keyboard (??)) and
- created two services (Armoury Live Update and AsusROGLSLService Download ROGLSLoader) and set them to autostart.

Now, knowing how careless ASUS is with regard to security, as it was hacked, and signing keys were compromised, this is literally a stab in the back. Why does Windows Update install a driver that phones back to ASUS and later can download arbitrary code on my machine? (Note that a driver is running at elevated privileges).

I disabled the services, and set the mouse back to HID compliant mouse (and works fine), but I cannot disable the "TUF Gaming M5 keyboard".

Anyway, my system is considered compromised by this Chinese trash mouse and now I have to reinstall everything.

My question is: how can I enforce that no other drivers except directly from Microsoft are installed, even if I plug in an ASUS mouse? I would like to see this mouse as HID Compliant mouse, without any ASUS-specific bloatware/security hole.

Comment: Enforcing this is likely a non-starter. Turn off Driver Updates in Windows Updates and then change to a different mouse.

Comment: The fact that a company has been hacked does not necessarily mean that it was careless with security... ASUS probably is though.

Comment: @John: I will look into that on my computer, but thinking on a more global scale, what stops a user to plug in an ASUS mouse in their laptop? I have never seen any company that disallows this, and actually **driver** updates cannot be turned off (if yes, please tell me where, I cannot find that option/policy). I only found "automatically download manufacturers' apps", and that I turned off, I don't know if this solves the issue yet. I cannot switch to another mouse for awhile, shipping time is 3 weeks, but good advice anyway, thanks.

Comment: Considering the recent story about Razor mice giving you Admin permissions this is indeed a relevant question. https://securityboulevard.com/2021/08/this-mouse-gives-you-admin-on-windows/

Comment: I do not understand the downvote. The question describes a specific issue, the issue has major negative consequences (security hole), affects many users and in general follows the SE Q rules. Also, there are no other questions that answer this particular question. The "Device Installation Settings" setting of "no" makes this mouse not working. Other registry hacks as well. (I have tried these on clean installs.)

Comment: @Robert: Thank you for the link, super useful, so I am actually not too paranoid. :-)

Comment: Further discussion on a similar issue with Razor mouses: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/p9j0bu/windows_update_razer_usb_mouse_elevated_admin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable automatic driver updates:

- Run *Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings*
- Position to the Hardware tab
- Click "Device Installation Settings"
- Click "No (your device might not work as expected)"
- Click OK.

Comment: I have tried this on a clean install, but unfortunately the device does not work properly. II am going to debug why this mouse is not working as a generic HID mouse.

Comment: "can I enforce that no other drivers except directly from Microsoft are installed" is the question. Right now if I turn this setting to "No" the mouse is not even recognized, and no MS drivers are installed. This is a good answer overall but does not solve the described problem unfortunately. Please note that this may very well be a result of cr*ppy firmware or low compatibility of the mouse in general, so I have to debug more. You have my upvote though.

Comment: You could install the generic mouse either manually ("Add hardware"), or by enabling updates and connecting an ordinary harmless mouse and then disabling and connecting this mouse. Some devices don't work well with generic drivers, and in the case of this mouse Microsoft installs a driver that you don't like. Most "generic" drivers were not created by Microsoft.